# RaptureXML iterate:usingBlock warning and crash

Tags: ios, xml, nsarray, loops

I'm parsing an XML file which looks like this:

```
<partie numero="1">
      <exercice numero="1" libelle="blabla"></exercice>
      <exercice numero="2" libelle="anything"></exercice>
</partie>
```

I'm using the Rapture XML Library, so as explained on GitHub, I do the following :

```
RXMLElement *rxmlPartie = [rxmlParties child:@"partie"];
NSArray *rxmlUnExercice = [rxmlPartie children:@"exercice"];
```

I can print correctly the "numero" attribute from partie with this line :

```
 NSLog(@"Partie #%@",[rxmlPartie attribute:@"numero"] );
```

But when I try to use the iterate method on my NSArray :

```
[rxmlPartie iterate:@"partie.exercice" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement *exercice) {NSLog(@"Exercice: %@ (#%@)", [exercice attribute:@"libelle"], [exercice attribute:@"numero"]);}];
```

I get a warning, and the the application crash, saying :

```
-[RXMLElement iterate:usingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc67f870
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    [RXMLElement iterate:usingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc67f870'
```

Did I forget to import something, or do I implement the method in a bad way?

The same error happens if i try to use iterateWithRootXPath...

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found out what was my problem.

I didn't know anything about paring with Rapture XML before doing this...So I sticked to the doc (as somebody told me in school :-) ). But the problem was that a method used in the doc, this "iterate usingBlock" is not defined in the framework.

Instead of using

```
[rxmlPartie iterate:@"partie.exercice" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement *exercice)     {NSLog(@"Exercice: %@ (#%@)", [exercice attribute:@"libelle"], [exercice attribute:@"numero"]);}];
```

I'm using

```
[rxmlPartie iterate:@"exercice" with: ^(RXMLElement *exercice)     {NSLog(@"Exercice: %@ (#%@)", [exercice attribute:@"libelle"], [exercice attribute:@"numero"]);}];
```

Which is well defined within the framework!

It made my day!!

Comment: i can not find `[rxmlPartie iterate:@"exercice" with: ^(RXMLElement *exercice) ` this api.